# How can I set a connection time out manually?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sockets, timeout

I use

```
connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddr, sizeof(remoteAddr))
```

to connect my iPhone to a computer (over WIFI) and it works fine so far.
However if the computer is out of reach, my iPhone tries to establish a connection for more than a min.

Is there a posibility to set the time manually out to a new value, e.g. 15 sec?

Answer (score 0):

As you deal with low-level socket, the simplest way is to use the `setsockopt` function with the `SO_SNDTIMEO` key. See the [getsockopt/setsockopt man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getsockopt.2.html) for more information.